# Flutter [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: type 'FirebaseAuthException' is not a subtype of type 'String'

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

**Hi developers, I am getting this issue**

```
W/System  ( 7624): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
E/flutter ( 7624): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: type 'FirebaseAuthException' is not a subtype of type 'String'
E/flutter ( 7624): #0      CubitApp.userRegestration.<anonymous closure> (package:shoping_app/lib/shared/cubit/appcubit.dart:172:29)
E/flutter ( 7624): #1      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1434:47)
E/flutter ( 7624): #2      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1335:19)
E/flutter ( 7624): #3      _FutureListener.handleError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:177:22)
E/flutter ( 7624): #4      Future._propagateToListeners.handleError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:778:47)
E/flutter ( 7624): #5      Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:799:13)
E/flutter ( 7624): #6      Future._completeError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:609:5)
E/flutter ( 7624): #7      _completeOnAsyncError (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:272:13)
E/flutter ( 7624): #8      FirebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword (package:firebase_auth/src/firebase_auth.dart)
E/flutter ( 7624): <asynchronous suspension>
```

**on my flutter app when I was tried to create** `FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword`

and this is the function that I wrote:

```
void create_Account({
    required String firstName,
    required String lastName,
    required String userName,
    required String address1,
    required String address2,
    required String phone,
    required String email,
    required String passWord,
}){
  emit(RegisterLodingState());
  FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
      email: email,
      password: passWord,
  ).then((value) {
    emit(RegisterSuccessedState());
    print(value.user!.email);
    print(value.user!.uid);

  }).catchError((err){
    emit(RegisterErrorState(err));
    print('Error when Login :$err');
  });
```

**and this code when I call the function:**

```
ConditionalBuilder(
                      condition: true,
                      builder: (context) => defaultButton(
                        function: () {
                          if (formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                            cubit.create_Account(
                                firstName:firstNameController.text,
                                lastName: lastNameController.text,
                                userName: userNameController.text,
                                address1:addressOneController.text,
                                address2:addressTwoController.text,
                                phone: phoneNumberController.text,
                                email: phoneNumberController.text,
                                passWord: passwordController.text,
                            );
                          }
                        },
                        text: 'Sign Up',
                      ),
                      fallback: (context) => const Center(
                          child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
                    ),
```

Note:
*my emulator device is already connected with the internet and although I tried a physical device but the same problem.*

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to cast a `FirebaseAuthException` to a `String` which is incorrect so change this line:

```
print('Error when Login :$err');
```

to this:

```
print('Error when Login :${err.message}');
```

Also, take a look at [this document](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/error-handling/) to find out more about error handling in firebase.

Comment: Thank you so much for your interest, I tried it right now but unfortunately the problem is not solved

Comment: @YoussefElbtat what happens when you comment the print function?

Comment: the print sentence is not executed in the two cases my old code and the new one when you recommended. and both the current and the next Cubit app state is Instance of  RegisterLodingState So, I think the whole function (FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword) is not executed

Comment: @YoussefElbtat in your ide check what line gives the error. the log says the error is from casting.

Comment: yeah bro the error was in this line emit(RegisterErrorState(err)); and  I found that the reason is I have added a String parameter in RegisterErrorState Class and when I removed that parameter the problem is solved and the print sentence in .catchError executed and it shows ''Error when Login :The email address is badly formatted.'' but this new error I think is simpler and I will look for a solution. thank you so much sir for your time I really appreciate that, I wish I could confirm your answer, but unfortunately I am not yet allowed to confirm answers